typedefing the inherited templated base class with base ctors call
Following question that was answered
"typedefing" base class in templates
I reposting the question with refined conditions. As before the question is how to avoid retyping fully qualified name of inherited class type name several times in template specifications. The reason is that due to long list of arguments it is very prone to forgetting changing it in several places. The code may even compile in this case, and lead to difficult to debug errors.
Example of code to improve:
template<int Index, typename ... Rest>
struct Sequence
{
// ...
};

template<int Index, typename F, typename ... Rest> 
struct Sequence<Index, F, Rest ...> : public Sequence<Index+1, Rest ...>
{
    // can we improve retyping the base type definitions in ctor Sequence<Index+1, Rest ...>
    Sequence(int Param):Sequence<Index+1, Rest ...>(Param) 
    {
    } 
};

Pay attention to following:
a. The class derives from the same template (same name, different arguments)
b. It calls base class constructor.
Can we define the base class name only once and reuse it during template specification coding.

Nothing short of using a macro

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: #define the MACRO also takes place... Which arguments to pass to it? typedef seems to be equivalent to some possible MACROs...

@Jarod42 I interpreted StoryTeller's idea like this: #define BASE Sequence<Index + 1, Rest...> template <int Index, typename F, typename... Rest> struct Sequence<Index, F, Rest...> : public BASE { Sequence(int Param) : BASE(Param) {}

@TedLyngmo - Yup

Does defining an alias template count, or is that not enough shorter (in the cases of interest)?
